# mod-security causes segmentation fault

Tags: apache2, mod-security, mod-security2

I was trying to remove a rule (numeric ip in host header) for machines on my local network:

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch 192.168.178.0/24" \ 
"id:5,phase:1,t:none,nolog,pass,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=981203"
```

The rule is defined here:
`[file "/etc/apache2/crs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_60_correlation.conf"] [line "33"]`

After setting this rule every request caused a segfault:
`[Wed Oct 07 19:37:03.187960 2015] [core:notice] [pid 28950] AH00052: child pid 28983 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified:

```
ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=981203
```

But not specified a target. I'm guessing you meant:

```
ctl:ruleRemoveById=981203
```

?

Shouldn't cause a segfault ideally of course but it's still wrong.

Comment: Actually, this was causing a segmentation fault in my configuration. I was trying to exclude an specific file extension from a Core Rule Set rule but no specifying target via ARGS parameter as the CRS example shows.
It was fixed for me by using ctl:ruleRemoveById.
Thanks!